# Collect data from two lists to a dataframe with rbindlist lapply incorrect number of dimensions error

Tags: r, list, data.table, lapply

I am trying to find, where my mistake is.

From multiple excel files (each have Quality sheet and Quantity sheet), each file has one sample of data,
I import them (with read_excel to two different lists:

```
quant_list <- lapply(temp, function(x) read_excel(x,sheet = 'Quant_data'))

qualit_list <- lapply(temp, function(x) read_excel(x,sheet = 'Qualit_data'))
```

Then I need to collect some data from these lists and put them into a data.table
In rows there are samples, in columns there parameters,
some parameters are collected from qualit_list, some from quant_list

I've made a function, which makes a dt from each sample:

```
grab_fun <- function(qualit_list, quant_list_list) {
  data.table(Param1 = qualit_list[13:13, 7][[1]],
             Param2 = qualit_list[17:17, 7][[1]],
             Param3 = qualit_list[22:22, 7][[1]],
             Param4 = quant_list[10:10, 9][[1]])
}
```

It takes first three params from qualit_list,
and next params from quant_list

if I try the function on on one sample of data, it successfully returns a one row dt:

```
grab_fun(qualit_list[[1]], quant_list[[1]])
```

But if I try this on the whole data:

```
result_dt <- rbindlist(lapply(qualit_list, grab_fun, quant_list = quant_list))
```

- it returns an error:
  Error in quant_list[10:10, 9] : incorrect number of dimensions

It is interesting, that if I exclude a Param4 from the function grab_fun, so that it only uses data from qualit_list,
then the rbindlist with lapply works ok.

```
grab_fun <- function(qualit_list, quant_list_list) {
  data.table(Param1 = qualit_list[13:13, 7][[1]],
             Param2 = qualit_list[17:17, 7][[1]],
             Param3 = qualit_list[22:22, 7][[1]])
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach may be:

```
rbindlist(Map(grab_fun, qualit_list, quant_list))
```

As for your error above, this is caused because you are inadvertantly passing the entire set of Quantity Sheets  (i.e. the entire `quant_list` list) to the `grab_fun` for each element of `qualit_list`.

If trying to do this with lapply, you could use `seq_along` instead, like this:

```
rbindlist(
  lapply(seq_along(qualit_list), \(i) grab_fun(qualit_list[[i]], quant_list[[i]]))
)
```

Comment: Wonderful! Your  answer works well. Will try to learn about my error some more, due to your suggestion, thank you!

Comment: This is a great demonstration of the relative use of `Map`-vs-`lapply`. I find many that think they "get" `lapply` have a harder time with `Map`, and your side-by-side comparison of the two does a good job demonstrating it.